# Model datalog queries client side

Tags: architecture, datomic, datalog

I have datomic DB and going to build web-interface to query the database.

The straightforward solution I always implemented with relational databases is to write server API to retrieve entities.
Each API end-point has list of parameters it accepts, generates query, feeds the query to database, and returns results to browser after optional post-processing.

Now with datomic I'd like to try different approach.
What I want is to have single API end-point accepting query itself as parameter and to build query on client side.

Something like:

```
/api/1/query?q=[:find ?e :where [?e :entity/prop1 "value1"][?e :entity/prop2 "value2"]]
```

My questions are:

1. Is this approach is ok or there will be difficulties that I don't see now?
2. Are there any JavaScript/ClojureScript libraries I'd use? (I've seen at datascript, but it seems that the library is for building datomic-like DB on client and need to communicate with real datomic DB instead.
3. Any other advises in context of described architectures?

Thank you.

Comment: Depending on the purpose of your app, you might have problems with security. This way, user can construct any query they want and it is hard for you to do some reasoning about it.

Comment: You're right about the Datascript; from what you wrote, it is not a good fit for your needs.